# PostgreSql: Getting strange-formated "timestamp with time zone"

Tags: database, postgresql, datetime, formatting, timestamp

I am inserting into the table with field type "timestamp with time zone" string "1858-11-17 01:09:05+0000" and getting back strage formated value "05:11:29+04:02:24".

Here is session

```
test=> create table ddtbl (val timestamp with time zone);
CREATE TABLE
test=> insert into ddtbl (val) values ('1858-11-17 01:09:05+0000');
INSERT 0 1
test=> select * from ddtbl;
             val              
------------------------------
 1858-11-17 05:11:29+04:02:24
```

Why is this happening and what is "+04:02:24" here ?

UPD: PostgreSQL version

```
% psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.4
```

UPD2: Local timezone

```
% date +%Z
YEKT
% date +%z
+0600
```

Comment: Don't know but it happens for any date before 1914-01-01 UTC

Comment: Strange, I can not find this in documentation

Comment: I'm not seeing this on 9.1.9. What is your locale set to, maybe relevant?

Comment: I'm on Linux 9.2.4 BRT time zone. It does not happen in [SQL Fiddle 9.2.4](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8/940) probably because the server is set at UTC

Comment: If I do `set timezone = 'utc'` it is back to normal.

Comment: Confirm. Setting timezone='utc' solves the problem. But what was it ? A bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an effect of the time zone. Before early 20th century many countries (like Germany or Russia) had completely different regimes like "mean solar time" which would not translate cleanly to UTC.

Therefore a time in time zone 0 (GMT at the time, as there was no UTC yet) would have an odd time offset when represented as local time for Yekaterinburg (Russia).

`+04:02:24` is the actual offset as compared to UTC.

Comment: so, this is 4 hours, 2 minutes and 24 secs ?

Answer (score -1):

It is interpreting your input value is UTC.

```
psql=# select cast('1858-11-17 01:09:05 UTC' as timestamp with time zone);
      timestamptz       
------------------------
 1858-11-17 01:09:05+00
(1 row)


psql=# select cast('1858-11-17 01:09:05 BRT' as timestamp with time zone);
      timestamptz       
------------------------
 1858-11-17 04:09:05+00
(1 row)
```

The two values are the just different representations of the same timestamp.

```
psql=# select cast('1858-11-17 05:11:29+04:02:24' as timestamp with time zone) = cast('1858-11-17 01:09:05+0000' as timestamp with time zone);
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Your answer is not related to question. Why is this happening and what is "+04:02:24" ? Your results does not describe this.

Comment: The +04:02:24 is the time offset from UTC into your locale

Comment: also see the [datestyle](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) parameter