# time zone confusion in relational databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I have downloaded a postgres database in .sql format. The type of temporal column in the database is: timestamp with time zone. And dates are mentioned in the database in the form given below:

```
 1866-05-17 05:53:28+05:53:28
 1901-09-28 05:53:20+05:53:20
 1960-01-01 05:30:00+05:30
 1944-07-21 06:30:00+06:30
```

Now I am unable to interpret as to what is meant by: e.g. "05:53:28+05:53:28". That is to which time zones do these times represent. And how should I convert these timestamps, such that a user may easily query to find out a persons date of birth without getting confused regarding the timezones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you don't have to worry about the odd time zone offsets. Internally, for a `timestamp with time zone` (`timestaptz` for short) only the count of seconds since '1970-01-01' in UTC time zone is stored.

The same is true for `timestamp` in MySQL 5.0 and above:
[Should I use field 'datetime' or 'timestamp'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/datetime-vs-timestamp/602038#602038)

If you are only interested in the `date`, you may want to convert the column from `timestamptz` to `date`. In Postgres, when casting to `date`, the `local` time zone is applied. Try:

```
SELECT '2013-05-21 00:19:50+02'::timestamptz::date
```

The odd time zone offsets are due to historically diverse regimes like "mean solar time" before the early 20th century. We had a similar question recently, where I answered with an explanation:
[PostgreSql: Getting strange-formated "timestamp with time zone"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572455/postgresql-getting-strange-formated-timestamp-with-time-zone/16573603#16573603)

More explanation for the Postgres data types `timestamp` and `timestamptz`:
[Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Answer (score 1):

"05:53:28+05:53:28" means the time `05:53:28` in a time zone that is 5 hours, 53 minutes and 28 seconds ahead of UTC.  In other words, that time is midnight UTC. Note that there is no actual time zone that is offset from UTC by 5:53:28.  Most time zones are offset from UTC by whole hours, a few by half hours, and even fewer (only a small hand full) by quarter hours.

In fact, every sample time you've provided is at midnight UTC, on different historical dates.